# super() in __init__ does not seem to implement default keyword arguments of the parent object

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a data type representing a (periodic) time interval following https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datetime-interval/0.2. I've defined an `Interval` object, and am trying to make a `PeriodicInterval` object inherit from it with the additional attribute `period`:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

class Interval(object):
    """
    An interval represents a duration of time and its location on the
    timeline. It can be any of the following:

    - start and end dates (or datetimes)
    - a start date (or datetime) and a timedelta
    - a timedelta and an end date (or datetime)

    Provides the following operators:
        for a date and an Interval:
            in
    """

    def __init__(self, start=None, duration=None, end=None):
        # Type checking:
        assert isinstance(start, date) or (start is None)
        assert isinstance(duration, timedelta) or (duration is None)
        assert isinstance(end, date) or (end is None)

        # Fill in the missing value:
        if (duration is not None) and (end is not None) and (start is None):
            start = end - duration
        elif (start is not None) and (end is not None) and (duration is None):
            duration = end - start
        elif (start is not None) and (duration is not None) and (end is None):
            end = start + duration

        # Assign the values:
        self.start = start
        self.duration = duration
        self.end = end

    def __contains__(self, time):
        """
        Checks if a date is contained within the Interval, e.g.:

        >>> datetime.now() in Interval(datetime.now(), timedelta(1))
        True
        """
        assert isinstance(time, date), "The argument 'time' should be a date."
        return (self.start <= time) and (time <= self.end)


class PeriodicInterval(Interval):
    def __init__(self, period=None, **kwargs):
        super(PeriodicInterval, self).__init__(kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    periodic_interval = PeriodicInterval()
```

However, this leads to the following `AssertionError` in the type checking:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/dev/scratch/Furion_scheduler/interval.py", line 67, in <module>
    periodic_interval = PeriodicInterval()
  File "/home/kurt/dev/scratch/Furion_scheduler/interval.py", line 50, in __init__
    super(PeriodicInterval, self).__init__(kwargs)
  File "/home/kurt/dev/scratch/Furion_scheduler/interval.py", line 20, in __init__
    assert isinstance(start, date) or (start is None)
AssertionError
```

I don't understand why instantiating a `PeriodicInterval` in this way leads to an error. If I instantiate an `Interval` using `interval = Interval()`, I don't get an error. What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to need to explode dictionary keyword arguments using the [double star](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (**) operator when calling parent constructor:

```
class PeriodicInterval(Interval):
    def __init__(self, period=None, **kwargs):
        super(PeriodicInterval, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I see. Within the `__init__` function of `PeriodicInterval`, `kwargs` is a dictionary, which needs to be unpacked with `**` in order to deliver keyword arguments to its `super`.

Comment: Yep. If you pass only `kwargs` and not `**kwargs` you will have the whole dict passed as the `start` argument of `Interval.__init__` and thus the very first assertion fails.